# Is Unity's EveryPlay is supported on desktop windows and mac?

Tags: everyplay

Is Unity's EveryPlay is supported on desktop windows and mac?

Thanks in advance.

Surya

Answer (score 0):

Everyplay currently supports iOS and Android, other platforms are not at this point supported.

Comment: Are they going to support in near future?Any idea on that.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide any timeline for expanding beyond iOS and Android. They come up in discussions every now and then, but at this point nothing more.